# How much storage do I have for photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-plus, online-storage, image-storage

I synchronise my photographs from my iPad with Google Plus and Dropbox. One day I found that Dropbox doesn't have enough space for my photos, but Google Plus takes all of them.

How much storage space do I have at Google Plus?

And another thing: does my storage space at Google Drive intersect with my storage space at Google Plus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos give you [15 GB of storage space for free](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6558). This storage limit only applies if you've chosen to upload ["Original" size photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156060) (bigger than 16 megapixels) on your desktop or with Auto Backup on your Android device.

Any photos you upload less than 2048px (or that you let Google+ resize for you) won't count against your limits.

Your storage is shared across Google Drive, Gmail, & Google+ Photos, but you can [buy more space](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/) if you're running low.

<sub>If you use Google Apps at work or school, you have at least 30 GB of storage.</sub>

Comment: So, if I have photos less then 2048px, I could download infinite count of them?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. At least that's what the links from Google say.

Comment: @loldop I think you mean upload, but yes you are correct.

Comment: So how come when I upload a bunch of 500x500 pictures to Google Drive, they still count against my storage limit?

Comment: @Michael upload them to Google+ Photos (Picasa).

Comment: Assuming I have many images in my Google+ account, how can I sort only those who count against my quota?

Comment: @Drazick that would be a separate question ;)

Comment: @AndrewLott, Do you think it has an answer? If it does, I will open.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to upload photo, use [Google Photo](https://photos.google.com/). It have unlimited space.

Comment: It offers unlimited space only if you limit yourself to the resolution they offer for limited space (1024px per side, if I recall). Google Photos has replaced Google+ Photos, so there's no way to not use it.